# The ForEach Loop Enumerator is Empty - SSIS Error when executing through CMD via VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ssis, ssis-2008

I am currently working on a SSIS package that is to be triggered through CMD via VBA (Access). All that the package does is read a bunch of files from a folder and upload them into a table in SQL Server.  The tricky part comes is that this folder location from which the package is to read the files is dynamic. Thnaks to STACKOVERFLOW, I figured out a way to make it dynamic, and the package is working good when executed from MS VS2008.

FUN PART : As the final link to complete the chain, I have used following in the cmd

```
dtexec \f "C:\Desktop\SSISAppend.dtsx" /Set "\Package.Variables[User::Directory].Property[Value];C:\Desktop\AppendFiles"
```

Throwing out an error :
Code : 0x8001C004
Description: The For Each File Enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that meatched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.

I have used the following variables:
"Directory"  against DIRECTORY in COLLECTION>>EXPRESSIONS in the ForEachfile Enumerator, 
"FilePath"   (With Index 0) in the Variable Mappings

When executed through MS VS2008, the package is running good with watever location mentioned against the variable DIRECTORY.

Appreciate all the help and do let me know if you need further info.

Comment: Does the user running the package has sufficient right on that folder?

Comment: yes, the user has the read/write access to the folder, infact the package runs good when executed from SSIS (MS VS) directly, but the problem arises when trying to execute from CMD

Answer (score -1):

Thinking on the same lines as @Joost comment with regards to permissions through Access/CMD.

Maybe you can try using RUNAS when starting CMD.

Using RUNAS command 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx
 :